# PWA Toolkit for Commerce Cloud

Tags: commerce-cloud

We have a usecase for a dealer quote submission app on mobile devices. Mobile publisher is not being preferred by client.

Is it possible to use PWA toolkit for B2C Commerce Cloud published by Salesforce, to create a PWA for dealer users?

PWA basically should be able to submit quotes in Salesforce Sales Cloud objects such Quote/Quote Line Item & related object Account/Opportunity/Opportunity Products.

Answer (score 0):

As the basis of the Composable Storefront is a React SPA, you can build whatever you want on it as long as there are APIs available!

So yes!